# Should I store the access_token in localStorage+Redux or in axios defaults?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, access-token

I started using Redux with my React application. In the beginning, I tried using [Dan Abramov's Tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage) to handle the management of the token with the subscribe function on the store object.

Now I saw, that I can directly save the token to the axios defaults like that: `axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];`

Is it bad practice to store the token to the defaults at the time I receive it in the API response? Should I do it with Redux instead?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store ur token in the `local storage`. In API call u can get token from local storage.

```
let webApiUrl = 'example.com/abc';
let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
let headers={headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`} }
axios.get(webApiUrl,headers);
```

Comment: But don't you think it's kinda bad practice to directly call the localStorage, if you're already using redux?

Comment: yes I have to make an API service and call API from that ex: get, post, put and delete  those 4 my main function and I have to code token for the same and use for the all function.

Comment: As you are using axios, unleash its power and store it there. If you switch to a different HTTP library later(very unlikely) you can think about other storage alternatives.

Comment: u can just set the token in the header when u can use any others library even u can use `fetch`, `axiox`, `superagent` etc. its best way to u can store ur token in local storage bcoz u can set in the redux state when u reload page redux state can clear.

Comment: @BrunoPaulino would you directly store it there, when you get it from the login-provider or would you also use a dispatch to keep it in sync with the store?

Comment: @Fabioha I would like the redux store out. Why would you need it in the store? to show it somewhere in the interface? I think letting axios only taking care of it leaves less space for errors.

Comment: @BrunoPaulino My intention was, to handle everything localStorage related with redux, since I already need it for the language settings. But you're right, it does leave less space for errors.